# How to display a numeric keyboard on start of an activity?

Tags: java, android

When I searched I got an answer but that didnt help me. Well.
Now, in my manifest file I used with that particular activity like this:
 android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible"
It works but shows only alpha keyboard! I want actually want numeric keyboard,please.

Comment: are you using any edittext on launcher activity?

Comment: Yes.Input is numeric.

Comment: Follow my answer on stackoverflow http://stackoverflow.com/a/39593871/1831494 and enjoy.

Comment: Follow my answer on below question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39593324/cannot-resolve-symbol-showsoftinput/39593871#39593871

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a particular EditText you want to have focus first for the numeric keyboard?

If so then try this on the relevant EditText:

XML:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/myEditText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number">
    <requestFocus/>
</EditText>
```

**OR** Runtime (onCreate):

```
EditText editText = new EditText(this);
editText.requestFocus();
editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
```

Comment: In XML inside edittext how to include <requestFocus/>. It is not accepting.

Comment: I have shown you above? Use one or the other, obviously not both. I have edited the xml version it to show as typical complete example. Also in your java file just addEditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myEditText);    hope this helps!

Comment: I used runtime (oncreate). It helped.

Answer (score 0):

In your focused EditText add this:
android:inputType="number"